# why does `DELIMITER //` gives error in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

when I run the command

```
DELIMITER //
```

it returns this error :

> #42000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMITER //' at line 1

```
show variables like '%version%'
```

returns

```
Variable_name           Value   
-------------           -----   
innodb_version          5.6.36-82.1 
protocol_version        10  
slave_type_conversions      
version                 10.0.32-MariaDB 
version_comment         Source distribution 
version_compile_machine     
version_compile_os      Linux   
version_malloc_library  system
```

What am i doing wrong ? From what version can I use the delimiter command ?

**edit:**

I tried this example from the comments : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/delimiters/
and it returns this error :

> #42000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMITER //
>
> CREATE FUNCTION FortyTwo() RETURNS TINYINT DETERMINISTIC
>
> BEGIN ' at line 1.

**SOLUTION :**
I did the command from `DataBase WorkBench v5.3.4b Lite` and it failed.
Now I downloaded `MySql WorkBench 6.3` and there the command works without any problem.

So the problem is in `DataBase WorkBench v5.3.4b Lite`.
I recommend to not use this tool.

My problem is that it also still fails in my Delphi 7 client, so I guess I need to find better connection components

Comment: is that the full command? The SQL error layout in general tends to suggest the error comes *before* the Delimiter

Comment: @Martin yes that is the full command

Comment: What happens when you [run this example](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/delimiters/)? By the looks of it your Delimiter needs to be set at the start of *another* instruction, using the set delimiter

Comment: Are you running this on a command line? if so, try `\d //` instead

Comment: @Martin I tried it and it fails. I edited my question with the result

Comment: Ok.... Do other commands work for you? The problem occurs before the first character of your command so that implies that other commands shouldn't work or that you're not in the "open" command prompt setting

Comment: I am doing the commands in Database Workbench v5.3.4b Lite

Comment: I can do select statements without problems

Comment: Create table also works

Comment: Ok, I have no experience of Maria DB or of Database Workbench but your comments mean it may be an error code here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-error-codes/ (search for `42000`). Can you get Database workbench give you any more verbose output?

Comment: @Martin I have no clue how to do that in workbench. Its my first time with that tool also

Comment: Not sure it is required, but do you have a newline after `//`?

Comment: Are you using the mysql commandline tool (which uncerstands `DELIMITER`)?  Or some other client (which probably does not)?

Comment: @Uueerdo Yes i have a new line

Comment: @RickJames I was trying with database workbench, but now i downloaded mysql workbench and here i do not get the error. So it is a problem with the DataBase WorkBench then ?

Comment: @Martin I found the problem and put to solution in my answer. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @RickJames, I found the problem and put to solution in my answer. Thanks for all your help

Comment: You need to understand that `DELIMITER` is not a MySQL or MariaDB keyword or function. It is a _client_ function implemented only in the `mysql` command line client and in Workbench. Other clients have their own methods (configuration parameter, input field, etc) for setting an alternate delimiter.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes I just figured that out. I am new to MairaDB and used to sql-server so I still got lots to learn

Comment: Glad you found the answer, @GuidoG  . You can answer your own question to correctly close this query.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the command from DataBase WorkBench v5.3.4b Lite and it failed.
Now I downloaded MySql WorkBench 6.3 and there the command works without any problem.

So the problem is in DataBase WorkBench v5.3.4b Lite.

Comment: Not very useful as an answer. I am also facing the same issue using TestContainer and MariaDB. So what is the best way to solve the issue ?

Comment: @HarryCoder Please read this comment from  Michael Berkowski:  You need to understand that DELIMITER is not a MySQL or MariaDB keyword or function. It is a client function implemented only in the mysql command line client and in Workbench. Other clients have their own methods (configuration parameter, input field, etc) for setting an alternate delimiter.

Comment: In other words, there is no other solution but to use a client tool that impements this command